# SMS not deleted

Tags: android, sms

I have a code to delete the SMS messages in the outbox with android, but why SMS messages are not deleted ..

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Dialogs.showConfirmation(LookSms.this,"Are you sure?",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
Intent i = getIntent();
String id_delete_sms = i.getStringExtra("protocol");
String id_delete_thread = i.getStringExtra("address");

// hapus pesan
Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");

getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri,"thread_id=? and protocol=?",
new String[] {String.valueOf(id_delete_thread),String.valueOf(id_delete_sms) });

finish();
Toast.makeText(LookSms.this,"SMS deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

hey use this code to delete customize sms 1. By date 2. By number 3. By body

```
try {
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person",
                        "date", "body" }, "read=0", null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);
                String date = c.getString(3);
                Log.e("log>>>",
                        "0--->" + c.getString(0) + "1---->" + c.getString(1)
                                + "2---->" + c.getString(2) + "3--->"
                                + c.getString(3) + "4----->" + c.getString(4)
                                + "5---->" + c.getString(5));
                Log.e("log>>>", "date" + c.getString(0));

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("read", true);
                getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),
                        values, "_id=" + id, null);

                if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                    // mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), "date=?",
                            new String[] { c.getString(4) });
                    Log.e("log>>>", "Delete success.........");
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log>>>", e.toString());
    }
```